# Unclear about default value for OCaml argument

Tags: arguments, ocaml, default

I am a bit unclear of what exactly will be the value of `var_c` in this function definition in OCaml. Is it assigning `var_c` a default value of the result of the function? Or a default value of `Enum.peek var_c` to var_c?

```
let rec read var_a ?(var_b = var_a) var_c = match Enum.peek var_c with
    None -> None
    ...
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var_c` does not have a default value in the snippet you posted. It is not optional and must be given as an argument. `var_b` does have a default value (namely the value of `var_a`).

`match Enum.peek var_c with ...` will be the result of the function. It is not the default value of anything.

Comment: One way to look at it is that the first `=` goes with the question mark (`?`).  The second `=` goes with the `let`.  So the first `=` gives a default value, the second `=` gives the body of the function.